# Impossible to add product to cart ERROR prestashop AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

My website is working fine until this early week, whenever customers try to add a product, it will come out with this error;

> Impossible to add the product to the cart.
>
> textStatus: 'parsererror'
>
> errorThrown: 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data'
>
> responseText:
>
> 45b
>
> {
>   "products": [ .....} 0

But if I put https://www.domain.com.au instead of www.domain.com.au, the AJAX won't throw any error.

There are few speculations I have here, but I have no solutions;
what I can think of that there is whitespace I need to delete, but I don't know where. And that the code that I put into my blockcart.php caused it;

> global $smarty;
>
> $smarty->assign('customerDefaultGroup' , Customer::getDefaultGroupId(Context::getContext()->customer->id));

But I tried to comment those out, it still throws me error.
SO for now, I disabled the AJAX but customers has started to complain that they are directed to shopping cart every time they add product.

And I don't know if this is related, I have random chars on my header every time I access the website.

Help

Following my ajax-cart.js for add function;

```
// add a product in the cart via ajax
    add : function(idProduct, idCombination, addedFromProductPage, callerElement, quantity, whishlist){
        if (addedFromProductPage && !checkCustomizations())
        {
            alert(fieldRequired);
            return ;
        }
        emptyCustomizations();
        //disabled the button when adding to not double add if user double click
        if (addedFromProductPage)
        {
            $('#add_to_cart input').attr('disabled', true).removeClass('exclusive').addClass('exclusive_disabled');
            $('.filled').removeClass('filled');
        }
        else
            $(callerElement).attr('disabled', true);

        if ($('#cart_block_list').hasClass('collapsed'))
            this.expand();
        //send the ajax request to the server
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType : "json",
            data: 'controller=cart&add=1&ajax=true&qty=' + ((quantity && quantity != null) ? quantity : '1') + '&id_product=' + idProduct + '&token=' + static_token + ( (parseInt(idCombination) && idCombination != null) ? '&ipa=' + parseInt(idCombination): ''),

            success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR)
            {
                // add appliance to whishlist module
                if (whishlist && !jsonData.errors)
                    WishlistAddProductCart(whishlist[0], idProduct, idCombination, whishlist[1]);

                // add the picture to the cart
                var $element = $(callerElement).parent().parent().find('a.product_image img,a.product_img_link img');
                if (!$element.length)
                    $element = $('#bigpic');
                var $picture = $element.clone();
                var pictureOffsetOriginal = $element.offset();

                if ($picture.size())
                    $picture.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': pictureOffsetOriginal.top, 'left': pictureOffsetOriginal.left});

                var pictureOffset = $picture.offset();
                if ($('#cart_block')[0] && $('#cart_block').offset().top && $('#cart_block').offset().left)
                    var cartBlockOffset = $('#cart_block').offset();
                else
                    var cartBlockOffset = $('#shopping_cart').offset();

                // Check if the block cart is activated for the animation
                if (cartBlockOffset != undefined && $picture.size())
                {
                    $picture.appendTo('body');
                    $picture.css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': $picture.css('top'), 'left': $picture.css('left'), 'z-index': 4242 })
                    .animate({ 'width': $element.attr('width')*0.66, 'height': $element.attr('height')*0.66, 'opacity': 0.2, 'top': cartBlockOffset.top + 30, 'left': cartBlockOffset.left + 15 }, 1000)
                    .fadeOut(100, function() {
                        ajaxCart.updateCartInformation(jsonData, addedFromProductPage);
                    });
                }
                else
                    ajaxCart.updateCartInformation(jsonData, addedFromProductPage);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                document.write("Impossible to add the product to the cart.\n\ntextStatus: '" + textStatus + "'\nerrorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "'\nresponseText:\n" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                //reactive the button when adding has finished
                if (addedFromProductPage)
                    $('#add_to_cart input').removeAttr('disabled').addClass('exclusive').removeClass('exclusive_disabled');
                else
                    $(callerElement).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    },
```

My ajax-cart.js customization to check the minimum quantity

```
var href = $(this).attr('href').split('=');
            if(typeof href[4] === "undefined")
            { qty = href[3];} //array position changed to 3 after URL rewrite enabled.
            else{ qty = href[4];}
```

My blockcart-jsan.tpl code;

```
{ldelim}
"products": [
{if $products}
{foreach from=$products item=product name='products'}
{assign var='productId' value=$product.id_product}
{assign var='productAttributeId' value=$product.id_product_attribute}
    {ldelim}
        "id":            {$product.id_product},
        "link":          "{$link->getProductLink($product.id_product, $product.link_rewrite, $product.category, null, null, $product.id_shop, $product.id_product_attribute)|addslashes|replace:'\\\'':'\''}",
        "quantity":      {$product.cart_quantity},
        "priceByLine":   "{if $priceDisplay == $smarty.const.PS_TAX_EXC}{displayWtPrice|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8' p=$product.total}{else}{displayWtPrice|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8' p=$product.total_wt}{/if}",
        "name":          "{$product.name|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'|escape:'htmlall'|truncate:15:'...':true}",
        "price":         "{if $priceDisplay == $smarty.const.PS_TAX_EXC}{displayWtPrice|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8' p=$product.total}{else}{displayWtPrice|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8' p=$product.total_wt}{/if}",
        "price_float":   "{$product.total}",
        "idCombination": {if isset($product.attributes_small)}{$productAttributeId}{else}0{/if},
        "idAddressDelivery": {if isset($product.id_address_delivery)}{$product.id_address_delivery}{else}0{/if},
        "is_gift" : {if isset($product.is_gift) && $product.is_gift}1{else}0{/if},
{if isset($product.attributes_small)}
        "hasAttributes": true,
        "attributes":    "{$product.attributes_small|addslashes|replace:'\\\'':'\''}",
{else}
        "hasAttributes": false,
{/if}
        "hasCustomizedDatas": {if isset($customizedDatas.$productId.$productAttributeId)}true{else}false{/if},
        "customizedDatas":[
        {if isset($customizedDatas.$productId.$productAttributeId[$product.id_address_delivery])}
        {foreach from=$customizedDatas.$productId.$productAttributeId[$product.id_address_delivery] key='id_customization' item='customization' name='customizedDatas'}{ldelim}
{* This empty line was made in purpose (product addition debug), please leave it here *}
            "customizationId":  {$id_customization},
            "quantity":         "{$customization.quantity}",
            "datas": [
                {foreach from=$customization.datas key='type' item='datas' name='customization'}
                {ldelim}
                    "type": "{$type}",
                    "datas":
                    [
                    {foreach from=$datas key='index' item='data' name='datas'}
                        {ldelim}
                        "index":            {$index},
                        "value":            "{$data.value|addslashes|replace: '\\\'':'\''}",
                        "truncatedValue":   "{$data.value|truncate:28:'...'|addslashes|replace: '\\\'':'\''}"
                        {rdelim}{if !$smarty.foreach.datas.last},{/if}
                    {/foreach}]
                {rdelim}{if !$smarty.foreach.customization.last},{/if}
                {/foreach}
            ]
        {rdelim}{if !$smarty.foreach.customizedDatas.last},{/if}
        {/foreach}
        {/if}
        ]
    {rdelim}{if !$smarty.foreach.products.last},{/if}
{/foreach}{/if}
],
"discounts": [
{if $discounts}{foreach from=$discounts item=discount name='discounts'}
    {ldelim}
        "id":              "{$discount.id_discount}",
        "name":            "{$discount.name|cat:' : '|cat:$discount.description|truncate:18:'...'|addslashes|replace:'\\\'':'\''}",
        "description":     "{$discount.description|addslashes|replace:'\\\'':'\''}",
        "nameDescription": "{$discount.name|cat:' : '|cat:$discount.description|truncate:18:'...'|addslashes|replace:'\\\'':'\''}",
        "code":            "{$discount.code}",
        "link":            "{$link->getPageLink("$order_process", true, NULL, "deleteDiscount={$discount.id_discount}")}",
        "price":           "{if $priceDisplay == 1}{convertPrice|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8' price=$discount.value_tax_exc}{else}{convertPrice|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8' price=$discount.value_real}{/if}",
        "price_float":     "{if $priceDisplay == 1}{$discount.value_tax_exc}{else}{$discount.value_real}{/if}"
    {rdelim}
    {if !$smarty.foreach.discounts.last},{/if}
{/foreach}{/if}
],
"shippingCost": "{$shipping_cost|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'}",
"shippingCostFloat": "{$shipping_cost_float|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'}",
{if isset($tax_cost)}
"taxCost": "{$tax_cost|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'}",
{/if}
"wrappingCost": "{$wrapping_cost|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'}",
"nbTotalProducts": "{$nb_total_products}",
"total": "{$total|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'}",
"productTotal": "{$product_total|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'}",
{if isset($errors) && $errors}
"hasError" : true,
"errors" : [
{foreach from=$errors key=k item=error name='errors'}
    "{$error|addslashes|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'}"
    {if !$smarty.foreach.errors.last},{/if}
{/foreach}
]
{else}
"hasError" : false
{/if}
{rdelim}
```

Comment: Please provide a link to your site. If you don't want it to appear clearly for robot post it like this : "www---.---my---site---.---com". I might have a solution if I can see those extra chars in your header.

Comment: >{ "products": [ .....} 0
it looks like you have addtional zero (0) after json data, are you sure that you do not forget comment/delete something like `echo Customer::getDefaultGroupId();` or e.g.  in template `customerDefaultGroup`

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre the website is www---.---kdtrading---.---com.au  You need to do force refresh though to generate the random number. thank you!

Comment: @SergiiP You might going somewhere, I remembered I did testing before echo the customerdefaultgroup, But I just checked my code, it's ok.         if(!isset($groups[0])) $groups = FALSE;
                    $smarty->assign('customerGroups', $groups);    
        $defaultGroupId = Customer::getDefaultGroupId((int)$id_customer);     
    $customerDefaultGroup = new Group($defaultGroupId);    
    $smarty->assign('customerDefaultGroup' ,     $customerDefaultGroup);     
            }

Comment: I just realised the error thrown by Firefox and Chrome are different. In Chrome the error is                                                 Impossible to add the product to the cart.

textStatus: 'parsererror'

errorThrown: 'SyntaxError: 'Unexpected token c'                            responseText: 9ce                                                                           The responseText are not always the same though. It will throw this random numbers and chars and the alphabet will be picked up as 'unexpected token'

Comment: I just do not see the full code to fix the bug, so, I can give you only this advice, check step by step, including `override` classes if you have it, next: `CartController` method `displayAjax()` as you may see there is called `blockcart` module `hookAjaxCall()` method and there is tpl file that contains json template, maybe in one of these methods you have some debug info or something

Comment: @SergiiP I've looked at all these files so many times, hoping I did miss something but I still can't find any. I suspect it's my ajax-cart.js. I have updated my post with ajax-cart.js for add function. Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: ajax-cart.js just ask backend for data in json format, and in your case get wrong format (with additional characters) so I guess error on backend side. If you can't find anything I can advice you or use clean code base (e.g. replace some files using default installation files) or use diff tools to find changes. Also I hope you have disabled all caches.

Comment: @SergiiP Thank you for the quick reply. I have replaced all the files but the error is still there. And yes, i always clear the cache before testing any changes. Do you think there's any other problem that could cause this error besides the json format? I have updated my post with the json code that I have. I do have one change that is different from default one, which is on my ajax-cart.js (inside the theme so it will override the modules) to set my minimum quantity since we are wholesaler. I wonder if that would cause the problem?

Comment: oh, I missed one thing, so when you work with https protocol all works correct, no errors?

Comment: @SergiiP yes, no errors when it's on https://  I actually asked a friend to check for me through the FTP. He fixed it by passing the real Json data. It's like what you said Sergii regarding this unexpected token, but the funny thing is he checked all the php files, they are OK. So he's not sure as well how that random numbers and chars are mixed with the Json data. Should I marked this solved?

Comment: got it, unfortunately I missed this part before, in this case it looks like not a code bug, but very interesting. Need someone to take a look into your server software / code / logs etc. Right now I have no other ideas

Comment: ah, also I missed that you showed site url :) and now I see the problem, when I loaded page first time I got chars like "1044f" in first line. Also I think  I found the reason after some tests. After <body> tag you have line `<?php include_once("http://www.kdtrading.com.au/analyticstracking.php") ?>` - added by someone who not familiar with Smarty templates I guess. Deleting this line and/or fixing analyticstracking.php to avoid write something directly into browser will fix your json issues

Comment: @SergiiP I have commented out the analysistracking.php but the random numbers are still there. Can I use  $this->context->link->getPageLink('index',true);                              <?php include_once(" $this/analyticstracking.php") ?>  Should there by quotations in include_once()?  And now I am facing cache issue where customer log in on one page and other pages show he/she is not logged in. Will create new question for that. Thank you Sergii!